# Email harvest with python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I developed and application for harvest any type of emails from files
types : ishani@dolly.lk
        ishani(at)dit.dolly.lk
        ishani at cs dot dolly dot edu

But the problem is output shows some extra items in a list other than the extracted full email. I coudnt figure out why is that. I tried in various ways.I think there is a problem in my regular expression or the logic

here is my code

```
data=f.read()

    regexp_email = r'(([\w]+)@([\w]+)([.])([\w]+[\w.]+))|(([\w]+)(\(at\))([\w]+)([.])([\w]+[\w.]+))|(([\w]+)(\sat\s)([\w-]+)(\sdot\s)([\w]+(\sdot\s[\w]+)))'
    pattern = re.compile(regexp_email)
    emailAddresses = re.findall(pattern, data)

    print emailAddresses
```

the output is like this

```
[('ishani@sliit.lk', 'ishani', 'sliit', '.', 'lk', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''), ('', '', '', '', '', 'ishani(at)dit.sliit.lk', 'ishani', '(at)', 'dit', '.', 'sliit.lk', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''), ('', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'ishani at cs dot dolly dot edu', 'ishani', ' at ', 'cs', ' dot ', 'dolly dot edu', ' dot edu')]
```

but Im expecting a output like this

```
['ishani@dolly.lk','ishani(at)dit.dolly.lk','ishani at cs dot dolly dot edu']
```

Is there any method that anyone tried which support my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `regexp_email` to this:

```
r'[\w]+@[\w]+[.][\w]+[\w.]+|[\w]+\(at\)[\w]+[.][\w]+[\w.]+|[\w]+\sat\s[\w-]+\sdot\s[\w]+\sdot\s[\w]+'
```

It doesn't seem that you need the capturing groups, so I have removed all of them.

You also don't need the `[]` around `\w` if `\w` is all you need to specify:

```
r'\w+@\w+[.]\w+[\w.]+|\w+\(at\)\w+[.]\w+[\w.]+|\w+\sat\s[\w-]+\sdot\s\w+\sdot\s\w+'
```

Comment: In your solution its spliting to character by character. But Im expectivng the whole email address in one element of the list
like this 
['ishani@dolly.lk','ishani(at)dit.dolly.lk','ishani at cs dot dolly dot edu']

Comment: @Ishani702: It does what you want. What are you talking about?

Comment: your results shows like this
['n', 'u', 'w', 'a', 'n', '@', 's', 'l', 'i', 'i', 't', '.', 'l', 'k', 'n', 'u', 'w', 'a', 'n', '(', 'a', 't', ')', 'd', 'i', 't', '.', 's', 'l', 'i', 'i', 't', '.', 'l', 'k', 'n', 'u', 'w', 'a', 'n', ' ', 'a', 't', ' ', 'c', 's', ' ', 'd', 'o', 't', ' ', 's', 'l', 'i', 'i', 't', ' ', 'd', 'o', 't', ' ', 'e', 'd', 'u']
what im expecting is like this 
['ishani@dolly.lk','ishani(at)dit.dolly.lk','ishani at cs dot dolly dot edu']

Comment: @Ishani702: Probably something else that causes it. It works fine on ideone (Python 2.7.3): http://ideone.com/zzbLPr

Answer (score -1):

You could just skip the blanks

```
print [e for ea in emailAddresses for e in ea if e]
```

which produces

```
['ishani@sliit.lk', 'ishani', 'sliit', '.', 'lk', 'ishani(at)dit.sliit.lk', 'ishani', '(at)', 'dit', '.', 'sliit.lk', 'ishani at cs dot dolly dot edu', 'ishani', ' at ', 'cs', ' dot ', 'dolly dot edu', ' dot edu']
```

which isn't *exactly* what you asked for...

Comment: are there any other way to extract that kind of emails other than my way...?